# How and why using scripts with H2 Spring Database

Tags: java, spring, h2

I intend to make a program running with these requirements:

1. At the start of the application the program checks if there was
   already a database created
2. If not: Create one
3. If yes: Use it
4. The database stores and updates data (Customers.java) during the
   runtime.
5. As soon as the application gets closed the database
   should keep storing the data for the next execution.

So far the plan.

At the moment I have that basic code to test the functionallity **in my implementation**

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan()
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    QueryRepoImp queryRepoImp;

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    /*
        CreateH2Database createH2Database = new CreateH2Database();
        createH2Database.create();
        */
    }


    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner clr() {

        return a -> {
            log.info("Creating tables");

            // jdbcTemplate.execute("DROP TABLE customers IF EXISTS");
            jdbcTemplate.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customers(" +
                    "id SERIAL, first_name VARCHAR(255), last_name VARCHAR(255))");

            // Split up the array of whole names into an array of first/last names
            List<Object[]> splitUpNames = Arrays.asList("John Woo", "Jeff Dean", "Josh Bloch", "Josh Long").stream()
                    .map(name -> name.split(" "))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            // Use a Java 8 stream to print out each tuple of the list
            splitUpNames.forEach(name -> log.info(String.format("Inserting customer record for %s %s", name[0], name[1])));

            // Uses JdbcTemplate's batchUpdate operation to bulk load data
            jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("INSERT INTO customers(first_name, last_name) VALUES (?,?)", splitUpNames);

            log.info("Querying for customer records where first_name = 'Josh':");
            jdbcTemplate.query(
                    "SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM customers WHERE first_name = ?", new Object[]{"Josh"},
                    (rs, rowNum) -> new Customer(rs.getLong("id"), rs.getString("first_name"), rs.getString("last_name"))
            ).forEach(customer -> log.info(customer.toString()));
        };
    }
}
```

I saw some tutorials where people created a database with a script like this (**different implementation**):

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class SpringRootConfig {

    @Bean(name = "scriptedDataSource")
    public DataSource datasource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).addScript("script.sql").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcOperations jdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("scriptedDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```

**script.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
  id      IDENTITY,
  section VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
);
```

- I don't understand the pro/cons of that implementation?
- Why should I use a script like script.sql to create a table?

Can someone explain it please to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using **JdbcTemplate** Db and Table won't be available in database for that we import script.sql for create Table's

In case if you are using hibernate by setting hibernate property **hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto**  create/update/etc..

it will satisfy your 5th question

(5. As soon as the application gets closed the database should keep storing the data for the next execution)

Comment: But I use JdbcTemplate in my application with "CREATE TABLE" and it is working. So it seems to be available?

Comment: But you wrote "JdbcTemplate Db and Table won't be available in database " I mean I don't use hibernate and the tutorials I saw also not. Sorry can you explain in a different way what you mean please? Thank you :)

Comment: while deploying a project into different server at that time there is no table available in database for that script.sql file will help you to create table, no need of manual table creation in a database